# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook

Tags: java, apache, maven

He creado una app en NetBeans, y al compilar el proyecto la app funciona correctamente. Al exportar un `jar` con Build (construir) el abrir el archivo mediante CMD `java -jar app.jar` me lanza la siguiente exception:

```java
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
        at Frames.LCDAMain.searchActionPerformed(LCDAMain.java:625)
        at Frames.LCDAMain.access$1400(LCDAMain.java:21)
        at Frames.LCDAMain$9.actionPerformed(LCDAMain.java:391)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 40 more
```

En mi app se lee un acrchivo excell, empleando la librería de Apache Poi. Para la distribución de las dependencias y librerías uso Maven, y en el POM.xml del proyecto tengo (las dependencias están aisladas al final) :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>LCDAmanger</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        
<plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>Frames.LCDAMain</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
        </configuration>
        </plugin>
       </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-compress -->
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>config/sun_checks.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

    <dependencies>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
     <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
     <version>4.1.2</version>
     <type>jar</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
     <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
     <version>1.13</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La forma más sencilla, si el uno está desarrollando su proyecto usando Maven, es que utilice el Plug-In de [Maven Shade](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/).

Lo que está pasando aquí es que el `Jar` resultante no tiene recogido también las dependencias/librerías.
Por ello es necesario que se especifique en el POM.xml de Maven añadiendo el siguiente plug-in:

```xml
<plugins>
<!-- TUS PLUG-INS -->
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.4</version> <!-- ESCOGE LA ÚLTIMA VERSIÓN -->
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <transformers>
                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass>"MiPaquete.NombreDeMiClaseMain"</mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

<!-- TUS PLUG-INS -->

</plugins>
```

Lo elegante de esto, es que el próximo paso para construir el `Jar` es tan simple como hacer click en `Build` (o contruir) con el símbolo de martillo en NetBeans y listo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que el jar que estás generando no contiene ninguna dependencia más allá de las bibliotecas estándar provistas por el JRE.
Una manera de solucionarlo es crear un "fat jar" que contiene todas tus dependencias en un solo jar, y es fácil de copiar o mover a otros servidores o PCs
En Netbeans no lo puedes hacer directamente, pero aquí tiene una explicación de cómo hacerlo: https://www.nysimtech.com/2019/02/05/como-crear-un-fat-jar-en-netbeans/
Otra opción es utilizar el plugin maven-assembly y crear ej JAR con Maven.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Para incorporar todas las dependencias como tú dices, ¿cuál método es más correcto? hablando en términos de estabilidad y facilidad para hacerlo ¿por el fat Jar o con Maven?

Comment: Ambas opciones son para crear un fat jar, perdón si no fui claro, la diferencia es que una lo haces dentro de NetBeans, y la otra desde la línea de comandos, pero el resultado es el mismo.

Comment: He tenido problemas por ambas vías. Por NetBeans el problema persiste en que no tengo el Build.xml dado que trabajo con Maven. Por la terminal tampoco funciona y se debe una vez que se crean el Fat Jar con el problema: ```no hay ningún atributo de manifiesto principal en .\MIAPP-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar```